# Matching diverse dates in Openrefine

Tags: regex, date, openrefine

I am trying to use the value.match command in OpenRefine 2.6 for splitting the information presents in a column into (at least) 2 columns.
The data are, however, quite messed up.
I have sometimes full dates:

`May 30, 1949`

Sometimes full dates are combined with other dates and attributes:

`May 30, 1949, published 1979`
`May 30, 1949 and 1951, published 1979`
`May 30, 1949, printed 1980`
`May 30, 1949, print executed 1988`
`May 30, 1949, prints executed 1988`
`published 1940`

Sometimes you have timespan:

`1905-05` OR `1905-1906`

Sometimes only the year

`1905`

Sometimes year with attributes

`August or September 1908`

Doesn't seems to follow any specific schema or order.
I would like to extract (at least)ca start and end date year, in order to have two columns:

```
-----------------------  
|start_date | end_date|  
|1905       | 1906    |   
-----------------------
```

without the rest of the attributes.

I can find the last date using
`value.match(/.*(\d{4}).*?/)[0]`
and the first one with
`value.match(/.*^(\d{4}).*?/)[0]`
but I got some trouble with the two formulas.
The latter cannot match anything in case of:
`May 30, 1949 and 1951, published 1979`
while in the case of:
`Paris, winter 1911-12`
The latter formula cannot match anything and the former formula match 1911

Anyone know how I can resolve the problem?
I would need a solution that take the first date as start_date and final date as end_date, or better (don't know if it is possible) earliest date as start_date and latest date as end_date.
Moreover, I would be glad to have some clue about how to extract other information, such as 
if *published* or *printed* or *executed* is present in the text -> copy date to a new column name “execution”.
should be something like create a new column
`if(value.match("string1|string2|string3" + (\d{4}), "perform the operation", do nothing)`

Comment: In your example (where you said Sometimes full dates are combined with other dates and attributes), can you tell for each line what should be start_date and end_date ? It's not clear.

Comment: Quite right. I would go for first date as start_date and final date as end_date, or better (don't know if it is possible) earliest date as start_date and latest date as end_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value.match()` is a very useful but sometimes tricky function. To extract a pattern from a text, I prefer to use Python/Jython's regular expressions :

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\d{4}")

return pattern.findall(value)
```

From there, you can create a string with all the years concatenated:

```
return ",".join(pattern.findall(value))
```

Or select only the first:

```
return pattern.findall(value)[0]
```

Or the last:

```
return pattern.findall(value)[-1]
```

etc.

Same thing for your sub-question:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(published|printed|executed)\s+(\d+)")

return pattern.findall(value)[0][1]
```

Or :

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(published|printed|executed)\s+(\d+)")

m = re.search(pattern, value)

return m.group(2)
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: This works greatly :) I will wait to see if there is some other regex possibilities, just to clear up my mind, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex which will extract `start_date` and `end_date` in named groups :

If there is only one date, then it consider it's the *start_date* :

`((?<start_date>\d{4}).*?)?(?<end_date>\d{4}|(?<=-)\d{2})?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kmc5De/6)

Comment: Updated to match end_date with 2 digits precedeed by a hyphen